# freeradius daloradius authentication failure

Tags: radius, freeradius

i followed this tutorial to install freeradius and dalo radius for the raspberry pi:

http://www.binaryheartbeat.net/2013/12/raspberry-pi-based-freeradius-server.html

i tested the file authentication and it worked fine but after installing daloradius and switching to MySQL authnetications fail for unknown reasons

here is freeradius output that occurs when trying to authenticate a user:

```
 rad_recv: Access-Request packet from host 192.168.1.1 port 32779, id=216, length=172
        User-Name = "ccc"
        State = 0xf9775519ff7f4c9188c14494359a170f
        EAP-Message = 0x0208005b190017030100500d2898ca35aa9fa9e4febd8816c9e6deda71960fe5692b7c3d0499f2b5bba6b531483e373e14f8aff517aa081e214edc98e2c8bb22d16a961ecff4f498d20d152535b4d11ace1484b985bd2501ade77b
        Service-Type = Framed-User
        Framed-MTU = 1420
        NAS-IP-Address = 192.168.1.1
        Message-Authenticator = 0x49fc781b8a152fbec467b2c1f275a1a1
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: # Executing section authorize from file /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: +group authorize {
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: ++[preprocess] = ok
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: ++[chap] = noop
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: ++[mschap] = noop
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: ++[digest] = noop
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [suffix] No '@' in User-Name = "ccc", looking up realm NULL
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [suffix] No such realm "NULL"
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: ++[suffix] = noop
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [eap] EAP packet type response id 8 length 91
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [eap] Continuing tunnel setup.
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: ++[eap] = ok
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: +} # group authorize = ok
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: Found Auth-Type = EAP
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: # Executing group from file /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: +group authenticate {
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [eap] Request found, released from the list
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [eap] EAP/peap
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [eap] processing type peap
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [peap] processing EAP-TLS
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [peap] eaptls_verify returned 7
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [peap] Done initial handshake
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [peap] eaptls_process returned 7
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [peap] EAPTLS_OK
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [peap] Session established.  Decoding tunneled attributes.
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [peap] Peap state phase2
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [peap] EAP type mschapv2
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [peap] Got tunneled request
        EAP-Message = 0x0208003e1a0208003931461c2f1334a4b7bab38912e9d82dd97b000000000000000070fb7810a938a00d884f17dc01b62eaa7dde9fbb7ab2cf4200636363
server  {
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [peap] Setting User-Name to ccc
Sending tunneled request
        EAP-Message = 0x0208003e1a0208003931461c2f1334a4b7bab38912e9d82dd97b000000000000000070fb7810a938a00d884f17dc01b62eaa7dde9fbb7ab2cf4200636363
        FreeRADIUS-Proxied-To = 127.0.0.1
        User-Name = "ccc"
        State = 0x4bb6eef44bbef48a7072f4e023895561
server inner-tunnel {
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: # Executing section authorize from file /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/inner-tunnel
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: +group authorize {
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: ++[chap] = noop
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: ++[mschap] = noop
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [suffix] No '@' in User-Name = "ccc", looking up realm NULL
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [suffix] No such realm "NULL"
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: ++[suffix] = noop
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: ++update control {
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: ++} # update control = noop
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [eap] EAP packet type response id 8 length 62
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [eap] No EAP Start, assuming it's an on-going EAP conversation
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: ++[eap] = updated
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: ++[files] = noop
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: ++[expiration] = noop
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: ++[logintime] = noop
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: ++[pap] = noop
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: +} # group authorize = updated
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: Found Auth-Type = EAP
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: # Executing group from file /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/inner-tunnel
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: +group authenticate {
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [eap] Request found, released from the list
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [eap] EAP/mschapv2
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [eap] processing type mschapv2
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [mschapv2] # Executing group from file /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/inner-tunnel
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [mschapv2] +group MS-CHAP {
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [mschap] No Cleartext-Password configured.  Cannot create LM-Password.
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [mschap] No Cleartext-Password configured.  Cannot create NT-Password.
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [mschap] Creating challenge hash with username: ccc
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [mschap] Client is using MS-CHAPv2 for ccc, we need NT-Password
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [mschap] FAILED: No NT/LM-Password.  Cannot perform authentication.
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [mschap] FAILED: MS-CHAP2-Response is incorrect
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: ++[mschap] = reject
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: +} # group MS-CHAP = reject
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [eap] Freeing handler
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: ++[eap] = reject
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: +} # group authenticate = reject
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: Failed to authenticate the user.
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: Using Post-Auth-Type REJECT
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: # Executing group from file /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/inner-tunnel
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: +group REJECT {
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [attr_filter.access_reject]    expand: %{User-Name} -> ccc
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Debug: attr_filter: Matched entry DEFAULT at line 11
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: ++[attr_filter.access_reject] = updated
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: +} # group REJECT = updated
} # server inner-tunnel
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [peap] Got tunneled reply code 3
        MS-CHAP-Error = "\010E=691 R=1"
        EAP-Message = 0x04080004
        Message-Authenticator = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [peap] Got tunneled reply RADIUS code 3
        MS-CHAP-Error = "\010E=691 R=1"
        EAP-Message = 0x04080004
        Message-Authenticator = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [peap] Tunneled authentication was rejected.
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [peap] FAILURE
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: ++[eap] = handled
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: +} # group authenticate = handled
Sending Access-Challenge of id 216 to 192.168.1.1 port 32779
        EAP-Message = 0x0109002b190017030100205991bfd8f9e7f70794477d653c848e8b443626b3b935a5b3f049ac7af1534d3e
        Message-Authenticator = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000
        State = 0xf9775519fe7e4c9188c14494359a170f
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: Finished request 7.
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Debug: Going to the next request
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Debug: Waking up in 0.4 seconds.
rad_recv: Access-Request packet from host 192.168.1.1 port 32779, id=217, length=124
        User-Name = "ccc"
        State = 0xf9775519fe7e4c9188c14494359a170f
        EAP-Message = 0x0209002b190017030100202a7f1a72de2970b689e44c005661d1e1e444854af7499ebeb23eabc7bfad7b64
        Service-Type = Framed-User
        Framed-MTU = 1420
        NAS-IP-Address = 192.168.1.1
        Message-Authenticator = 0xc9b0d8e268df2d8e4b484725c3efa189
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: # Executing section authorize from file /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: +group authorize {
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: ++[preprocess] = ok
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: ++[chap] = noop
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: ++[mschap] = noop
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: ++[digest] = noop
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [suffix] No '@' in User-Name = "ccc", looking up realm NULL
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [suffix] No such realm "NULL"
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: ++[suffix] = noop
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [eap] EAP packet type response id 9 length 43
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [eap] Continuing tunnel setup.
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: ++[eap] = ok
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: +} # group authorize = ok
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: Found Auth-Type = EAP
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: # Executing group from file /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: +group authenticate {
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [eap] Request found, released from the list
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [eap] EAP/peap
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [eap] processing type peap
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [peap] processing EAP-TLS
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [peap] eaptls_verify returned 7
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [peap] Done initial handshake
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [peap] eaptls_process returned 7
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [peap] EAPTLS_OK
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [peap] Session established.  Decoding tunneled attributes.
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [peap] Peap state send tlv failure
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [peap] Received EAP-TLV response.
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [peap]  The users session was previously rejected: returning reject (again.)
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [peap]  *** This means you need to read the PREVIOUS messages in the debug output
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [peap]  *** to find out the reason why the user was rejected.
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [peap]  *** Look for "reject" or "fail".  Those earlier messages will tell you.
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [peap]  *** what went wrong, and how to fix the problem.
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [eap] Handler failed in EAP/peap
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [eap] Failed in EAP select
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: ++[eap] = invalid
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: +} # group authenticate = invalid
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: Failed to authenticate the user.
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: Using Post-Auth-Type REJECT
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: # Executing group from file /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: +group REJECT {
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [sql]  expand: %{User-Name} -> ccc
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [sql] sql_set_user escaped user --> 'ccc'
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [sql]  expand: %{User-Password} ->
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [sql]  ... expanding second conditional
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [sql]  expand: %{Chap-Password} ->
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [sql]  expand: INSERT INTO radpostauth                           (username, pass, reply, authdate)                           VALUES (                           '%{User-Name}',                           '%{%{User-Password}:-%{Chap-Password}}',                           '%{reply:Packet-Type}', '%S') -> INSERT INTO radpostauth                           (username, pass, reply, authdate)                           VALUES (                           'ccc',                           '',                           'Access-Reject', '2015-12-29 18:38:47')
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Debug: rlm_sql (sql) in sql_postauth: query is INSERT INTO radpostauth                           (username, pass, reply, authdate)                           VALUES (                           'ccc',                           '',                           'Access-Reject', '2015-12-29 18:38:47')
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Debug: rlm_sql (sql): Reserving sql socket id: 29
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Debug: rlm_sql (sql): Released sql socket id: 29
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: ++[sql] = ok
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: [attr_filter.access_reject]    expand: %{User-Name} -> ccc
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Debug: attr_filter: Matched entry DEFAULT at line 11
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: ++[attr_filter.access_reject] = updated
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: +} # group REJECT = updated
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: Delaying reject of request 8 for 1 seconds
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Debug: Going to the next request
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Debug: Waking up in 0.1 seconds.
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: Cleaning up request 0 ID 209 with timestamp +11
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Debug: Waking up in 0.3 seconds.
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Info: Cleaning up request 1 ID 210 with timestamp +11
Tue Dec 29 18:38:47 2015 : Debug: Waking up in 0.3 seconds.
Tue Dec 29 18:38:48 2015 : Info: Cleaning up request 2 ID 211 with timestamp +12
Tue Dec 29 18:38:48 2015 : Debug: Waking up in 0.1 seconds.
Tue Dec 29 18:38:48 2015 : Info: Sending delayed reject for request 8
Sending Access-Reject of id 217 to 192.168.1.1 port 32779
        EAP-Message = 0x04090004
        Message-Authenticator = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution,

the problem was that i didn't configure the **/etc/raddb/sites-available/inner-tunnel** file to use sql